# Collection upsert key values of passed in object

Tags: mongodb, meteor

This Meteor server code tries to upsert all the `key:value` pairs in `param` but instead it upsert(ed) the key as `param`.
Prefere with out a loop. How can it be done so that the keys of `param` is upserted and not the key "param"? Thanks

```
let param = {a: '1', b: '2'};
myCollection.upsert({param}, {param});

meteor:PRIMARY> db.myCollection.find().pretty()

//now
_id: "...",
param: {a: '1', b: '2'};

//desired
_id: "..."
a: 1,
b: 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are param variable store the object you want. When you use {param} in the upsert method, you are doing this:

{
  param: {
    a: '1',
    b: '2'
  }
}

Try this just param, without {}.

Answer (score 0):

The upsert method needs two parameters, right? The first one, is the _id. The second is the object with the params you want. Try this:

myCollection.upsert({_id: ""}, {a: '1', b: '2'});